# How to query for AutoMapping on 0365 Mailbox using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline, office365, azure-powershell

I can enable and remove AutoMapping on a user/mailbox, but how can I query for it using powershell?
I've looked for the properties in `Get-MailboxPermission`, `Get-Mailbox` or `Get-AzureADUser` but couldn't find it. Nor any luck on Google.

It seems to be found in the property `msExchDelegateListLink` of `Get-ADUser`.
But I think `Get-ADuser` is deprecated or not for Azure/O365, so I don't wanna create scripts using that cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Source: https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/11355399-view-current-automapping-setting

Which is odd, at least, in my opinion :-/

Comment: It sure is odd! Thank for the link, now it got a vore more. And for everybody else, please up-vote-it